# Representing 2 binary digits in hex for vhdl

Tags: binary, hex, bit-manipulation, vhdl, hardware

In VHDL, If X'1 => "0001", X'3 => "0011". i.e, 1 hex digit represents 4 binary values, how do i represent only 2 binary values in hex given that i have only a specific bit range in memory. In this case 2. For instance, the space left in memory can only take 2 bits. I know i can still use the initial representation and mask out either the two msb's or lsb's but is there another way ?

Comment: Of course. The range is just limited. Hexadecimal is just a representation format (as is binary).

Comment: You question is unclear. Show a working example of masking out two bits in your application, it'll show what your doing with the 'bits'. Otherwise think an expression using  resize (a function, potentially custom) or  a slice (which requires a named array object or a function call returning an array value as a prefix).  There's also a length specifier for a bit string literal which can have it's length expanded or limited, see IEEE Std 1076-2008 8. Names, 8.1 for slice prefix, 15.8 Bit string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if you are using VHDL-2008:

```
2X"2" = "0010"
```

Further examples from web:

unsigned notation (default):

```
7UX"F"  = "0001111" -- extend
7UX"0F" = "0001111" -- reduce
```

signed noataion:

```
7SX"F"  = "1111111" -- extend
7SX"CF" = "1001111" -- reduce
```